# I have a web api that need to call 'Login' to get all needed information, how to avoid it being called everytime user call my API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

So, I have a web api that need to call Login function to get all needed information and return it to user.

```
    public string GetInfo(string username)
    {   
        Reddit reddit = new Reddit();
        reddit.LogIn("user123","pass123"); //moderator login, mandatory because without it GetUserInfo will return privilege exception

        return reddit.GetUserInfo(username);
    }
```

This means that everytime my API get called, it will go through login when I actually just need to do it once. How do I achieve this in WEB API?

Sorry for bad english

Comment: You are missing a lot of code here, too much so for us to be able to help you that much, but generally speaking it is best to create a `User` class with objects that store the user info, then initialize and populate it with your logon method then only reference the class object for the rest of your code.

Comment: just edited my question to clear the confusion.

Comment: still looks like you are not following normal convention of populating initializing a user class and referencing the object for needed information. Once you create and initialize an object with the user info there is no reason or need to continually re initialize it.

Comment: create a public class that has info such as username, email etc and whatever else you need to know about the user, then initialize that  with the response from your login method, then never use the login method again, only reference the user info object.

Comment: or if the reddit object already has all the info you need then just initialize that at a higher level of access so it can be accessed throughout your program instead of just inside your GetInfo object.

Comment: another thought, your object is designed to return a username, but the username must already be known because it is being passed as a arg to the method...

Comment: Make Login once ,and give the user **access-token** (Unique Random Number) that saved in the user cookies and after that every hit should be have the access-token and make sure to have Expire date for access-token

Comment: how do I achieve this? I mean my web API doesn't redirect user to oAuth page, that means no request token, access token, etc.  
  
User just need to hit my website like :  
warheat1990.com/api/getuserinfo/ahmed  
  
and it will automatically return json string

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a repository for user login status.

```
public string GetInfo(string username)
{   
    Reddit reddit = new Reddit();

    if (!LoggedIn(user))
    {
       reddit.LogIn("user123","pass123");
    }

    return reddit.GetUserInfo(username);
}
```

Comment: how do i achieve this? i mean because this is web api, user just need to hit something like warheat1990.com/api/getinfo/scott

that means everytime the api get called, reddit object will be in default state because new is called, hence the login will be required.

Comment: Consider using a try catch block then. Attempt to get user info. If an exception is thrown then loggin and then attempt to get user info again.